# SQL Server error selecting count on a subquery

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to select the count of the number of rows returned on a query.  The query is

```
Select 
    a.itm_cd, max(b.doc_num) ,max(c.text) 
from 
    ist b, itm_trn a, ist_cmnt c  
where 
    a.ist_seq_num = b.ist_seq_num 
    and a.ist_seq_num = c.ist_seq_num  
    and a.ist_wr_dt = b.ist_wr_dt 
    and a.new_loc_cd  like 'BOX115' 
    and a.ITT_CD = 'XFR' and a.create_dt >'21-AUG-16' 
group by 
    a.itm_cd;
```

For this particular query I return 3 rows,  I need to write a query that returns how many rows are returned.

I have tried this :

```
Select 
    count(*) 
from 
    (Select 
         a.itm_cd, max(b.doc_num), max(c.text) 
     from 
         ist b,itm_trn a, ist_cmnt c  
     where 
         a.ist_seq_num = b.ist_seq_num 
         and a.ist_seq_num = c.ist_seq_num  
         and a.ist_wr_dt = b.ist_wr_dt 
         and a.new_loc_cd  like 'BOX115' 
         and a.ITT_CD = 'XFR' 
         and a.create_dt > '21-AUG-16' 
     group by 
         a.itm_cd);
```

This results in a syntax error

> Msg 102, level 15, state 1 line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have a similar SQL statement that works this way in Oracle, but have not found where I am messing up in SQL Server.

**UPDATE:**

as per the first suggestion I received I tried :

```
Select 
    count(*)  
from 
    (Select 
         a.itm_cd, max(b.doc_num), max(c.text)
     from 
         ist b, itm_trn a, ist_cmnt c 
     where 
         a.ist_seq_num = b.ist_seq_num 
         and a.ist_seq_num = c.ist_seq_num  
         and a.ist_wr_dt = b.ist_wr_dt 
         and a.new_loc_cd  like 'BOX115' 
         and a.ITT_CD = 'XFR' 
         and a.create_dt > '21-AUG-16' 
     group by 
         a.itm_cd) as T
```

The errors returned were

> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
>   No column was specified for column 2 of 'T'.
>
> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
>   No column was specified for column 3 of 'T'.

Comment: you need to add an alias to your derived table: `group by a.itm_cd) as T;`

Comment: Tried that error I get is no column was specified for column 2 of 'T' and no column was specified for column 3 of 'T'

Comment: You don't even need those columns to calculate the count: `select count(*) from (select a.itm_cd. .......... group by a.itm_cd) as T;`

Comment: See update, still does not work.  I think it may have something to do with the fact I am looking for several columns, maybe I try minimizing.

Comment: did you read my last comment?, I said that you don't need those `max`, so either remove them or give them an alias

Comment: Sorry did not under stand,  I removed the max statements and it worked!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Old style joins are still being taught in schools as the way to do it. In fact you will see it in just about any tutorial out there, for just about any sql syntax available.  If there were some sort of standard, it is not being taught that way (which is probably why it hasn't been depreciated event though its been 20 years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per the error message, you should add alias name for your aggregated columns. Try like this,

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT a.itm_cd
        ,max(b.doc_num) AS MaxDoc_num
        ,max(c.TEXT) AS MaxText
    FROM ist b
        ,itm_trn a
        ,ist_cmnt c
    WHERE a.ist_seq_num = b.ist_seq_num
        AND a.ist_seq_num = c.ist_seq_num
        AND a.ist_wr_dt = b.ist_wr_dt
        AND a.new_loc_cd LIKE 'BOX115'
        AND a.ITT_CD = 'XFR'
        AND a.create_dt > '21-AUG-16'
    GROUP BY a.itm_cd
    ) T
```

You can easily find the count using this query.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT a.itm_cd)
FROM ist b
    ,itm_trn a
    ,ist_cmnt c
WHERE a.ist_seq_num = b.ist_seq_num
    AND a.ist_seq_num = c.ist_seq_num
    AND a.ist_wr_dt = b.ist_wr_dt
    AND a.new_loc_cd LIKE 'BOX115'
    AND a.ITT_CD = 'XFR'
    AND a.create_dt > '21-AUG-16'
```